# Is there a way to toggle fullscreen without destroying window/context?

Tags: c++, opengl, fullscreen, glfw, windowed

I currently have a game with OGL 4.5 and GLFW 3.

I'm trying to make a function that allows toggling between fullscreen and windowed modes. However, it seems in order to accomplish this, I have to destroy the current window and then create a new one in the same pointer (I red this in the GLFW documentation).

Although this works and I can swap between the two modes, it causes some crucial parts of the engine to stop drawing once the swap happens.

Due to this, I would like to know if there is some kind of way to enable / disable fullscreen without destroying the window and creating a new one.

This is the code of the function:

```
void TMooseEngine::toggleFullscreen()
{
    _fullscreen = !_fullscreen;

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    delete _shader;
    delete _skybox;
    //delete _particulas;




    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if(_fullscreen){ //change to fullscreen
       window = glfwCreateWindow(_width, _height, "Fate Warriors", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
       glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
       glViewport(0,0,_width,_height);
       //culling
       glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
       glViewport(0,0,_width,_height);
       glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
       glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
       glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
       _shader = new Shader();
       _skybox = new Skybox();

       initUI();
    }

    else{ //change to windowed
        window = glfwCreateWindow(_width, _height, "Fate Warriors", NULL, NULL);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glViewport(0,0,_width,_height);
        //culling
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glViewport(0,0,_width,_height);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
        _shader = new Shader();
        _skybox = new Skybox();

        initUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that answer is much more extensive than the one I provided. Personally, I think GLFW is horrible in this regard, SDL2 gives you the function `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen()` which just does the right thing. GLFW's `glfwSetWindowMonitor()` conflates toggling fullscreen with window resizing and positioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of GLFW, you can use the function `glfwSetWindowMonitor()` to toggle the fullscreen mode of an existing window, without having to destroy and recreate it.

The following command will change the fullscreen status depending on the `_fullscreen` variable:

```
glfwSetWindowMonitor(window, _fullscreen ? glfwGetPrimaryMonitor() : NULL, 0, 0, _width, _height, GLFW_DONT_CARE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't got the scope of the function the first time I red the documentation, but when you mentioned it, I went to the specification of the function itself and everything is crystal clear now. I have tried your solution and it works flawlessly